# List as variable/argument in Prolog

Tags: list, variables, prolog, arguments

I've created a function in Prolog to "turn" a list, e.g. to append the head of a list to the tail like so:

```
?- turn([a,b,c,d,e], Tlist).

Tlist=[b,c,d,e,a]
```

Within the context of my program, I'd like to be able to use predefined lists for the rule, such as

```
alist([a,b,c,d,e,f])
```

but I get lots of different errors. I've tried the following as arguments:

```
turn(alist(L),R).

listv(X) :- alist(L), member(X, L).
turn(listv(X),R).
```

and I understand that each of these are different representations of the list according to Prolog, but I'm not sure which list representation is appropriate to complete the operation on a predefined list.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't embed predicate calls such as `turn(listv(X), R)`. And what does that predicate/fact mean? It has two variables that aren't defined. You would need something like, `turned_lists(P, Result) :- call(P, L), turn(L, Result).` and call it as, `turned_lists(alist, Result).` or something like that, all depending upon what you're trying to achieve exactly (which isn't totally clear).

Comment: Oops, those are queries for existing predicates I've already made! Sorry for the lack of clarity there.

Answer (score 2):

The predicate `turn/2` can easily be defined based on [`append/3`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#append):

```
turn([A|As],Bs) :-
   append(As,[A],Bs).
```

For specifying some sample lists, we define an auxiliary predicate `named_list/2`:

```
named_list(one_to_nine        , [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]).
named_list(a_to_f             , [a,b,c,d,e,f]).
named_list(single_digit_primes, [2,3,5,7]).
```

Let's query!

```
?- named_list(a_to_f,Xs), turn(Xs,Ys).
Xs = [a,b,c,d,e,f], Ys = [b,c,d,e,f,a].    % succeeds deterministically

?- named_list(a_to_f,Ys), turn(Xs,Ys).     % "other" direction
  Ys = [a,b,c,d,e,f], Xs = [f,a,b,c,d,e]   % succeeds leaving behind choicepoint
; false.
```

So far, we have used one specific sample list `a_to_f` in the queries; let's use 'em all!

```
?- named_list(Name,Xs), turn(Xs,Ys).
  Name = one_to_nine        , Xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], Ys = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1]
; Name = a_to_f             , Xs = [a,b,c,d,e,f]      , Ys = [b,c,d,e,f,a]
; Name = single_digit_primes, Xs = [2,3,5,7]          , Ys = [3,5,7,2].
```